# Parsing json in Ansible AWS ec2_security_group to extract security group ids

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, ansible

This is a string/json/ansible parsing issue.

Big Picture: I'm creating a VPC, adding some security groups and creating some VMs.

The following example works fine with the output shown below.  However, I need to labels the newly-created security group IDs so I can use them to create VMs.

```
- name: Create an VPC and some security groups and show the security group ID
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    security_groups: []
    aws_region: "us-east-1"

  tasks:
    - name: "Create VPC test in AWS"
      amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_net:
        name: "test_vpc"
        cidr_block: "10.5.2.0/24"
        state: present
        region: "us-east-1"
      register: create_vpc_output

    - name: "Set VPC ID as fact"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        vpc_id: "{{ create_vpc_output.vpc.id }}"

    - name: "Configuring security groups for VPC {{ vpc_id }}"
      amazon.aws.ec2_security_group:
        name: "{{ item.value.name }}"
        description: "{{ item.value.description }}"
        tags:
          Name: "{{ item.value.name }}"
        state: present
        vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
      loop: "{{ query('dict', vpc_security_groups) }}"
      register: "create_sg_output"

      vars:
        vpc_security_groups:
          private_test1:
            name: "test1"
            description: "Allow all connections"
          private_test2:
            name: "test2"
            description: "Allow all connections"


    - name: Extract group_id and group_name
      set_fact:
        sg_groups: "{{ create_sg_output.results | map(attribute='group_id') | zip(create_sg_output.results | map(attribute='group_name')) }}"

    - name: Display extracted groups
      debug:
        var: sg_groups
```

Results:

```
TASK [Display extracted groups] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "sg_groups": [
        [
            "sg-08xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "test1"
        ],
        [
            "sg-05xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "test2"
        ]
    ]
}
```

How can I adjust this so the output is like this:

```
    "sg_groups": [
        {
            "group_id" : "sg-08xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "group_name" : "test1"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "sg-05xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "group_name" : "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the added 'group_id' and 'group_name' which is the labels for the data in the json returned from the [ec2_security_group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_security_group_module.html) call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more options:

- Use the filter [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/json_query_filter.html#ansible-collections-community-general-json-query-filter)

```yaml
  sg_groups: "{{ create_sg_output.results|
                 json_query('[].{group_id: group_id,
                                 group_name: group_name}') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  sg_groups:
    [
        {
            "group_id": "sg-08",
            "group_name": "test1"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "sg-05",
            "group_name": "test2"
        }
    ]
```

This option allows you to rename the attributes. For details see [JMESPath Specification](https://jmespath.org/specification.html).

- The next option is the filter [ansible.utils.keep_keys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/keep_keys_filter.html#ansible-collections-ansible-utils-keep-keys-filter). The below expression gives the same result

```yaml
  sg_groups: "{{ create_sg_output.results|
                 ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=['group_id', 'group_name']) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    create_sg_output:
      results:
        - group_id: sg-08
          group_name: test1
        - group_id: sg-05
          group_name: test2

    sg_groups: "{{ create_sg_output.results|map(attribute='group_id')|
                   zip(create_sg_output.results|map(attribute='group_name')) }}"

    sg_group2: "{{ create_sg_output.results|
                   json_query('[].{group_id: group_id,
                                   group_name: group_name}') }}"

    sg_group3: "{{ create_sg_output.results|
                   ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=['group_id', 'group_name']) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: sg_groups

    - debug:
        var: sg_group2|to_nice_json

    - debug:
        var: sg_group3|to_nice_json
```

---

- The simplest option is the filter *items2dict* if the values of *group_id* are unique

```yaml
  sg_groups_dict: "{{ create_sg_output.results|
                      items2dict(key_name='group_id',
                                 value_name='group_name') }}"
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  sg_groups_dict:
    sg-05: test2
    sg-08: test1
```

You can iterate the dictionary

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
      with_dict: "{{ sg_groups_dict }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'sg-08', 'value': 'test1'}) => 
  msg: sg-08 test1
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'sg-05', 'value': 'test2'}) => 
  msg: sg-05 test2
```

If you want to convert the dictionary to list use the filter *dict2items*

```yaml
  sg_groups: "{{ sg_groups_dict|
                 dict2items(key_name='group_id',
                            value_name='group_name') }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  sg_groups:
    [
        {
            "group_id": "sg-08",
            "group_name": "test1"
        },
        {
            "group_id": "sg-05",
            "group_name": "test2"
        }
    ]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    create_sg_output:
      results:
        - group_id: sg-08
          group_name: test1
        - group_id: sg-05
          group_name: test2

    sg_groups_dict: "{{ create_sg_output.results|
                        items2dict(key_name='group_id',
                                   value_name='group_name') }}"
    sg_groups: "{{ sg_groups_dict|
                   dict2items(key_name='group_id',
                              value_name='group_name') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: sg_groups_dict

    - debug:
        var: sg_groups|to_nice_json

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
      with_dict: "{{ sg_groups_dict }}"
```

Comment: This is a wonderfully helpful comment.  Thank you!  I've learned a lot.